# Estimate the number of words in audio record

Tags: audio-processing, speech-processing

I'm trying to estimate the number of words in a record

I tried to extract the Short term energy(STE) feature, denoise it, then count the number of peaks in the STE, it gives a very close result to the real number of words, but I'm struggling with the implementation since there are variables which vary from one record to another like speech rate for example

I also tried to transcribe the record then count the number of words but that's very slow and an estimate is enough for my task

Any help in counting the number of peaks or suggesting another approach would be appreciated

The attached image presents an example of STE and how number of every word gives a peak

Also the function of the STE (like the one in the image) varies a little bit from one speaker to another, for example another speaker's function could has peaks with lower values relatively

[image]

Comment: Could you please provide a better plot? This one doesn’t values and labels on it. The way it is presented could be anything; a time series of any value.